# Referencing module in Rails 5 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I created a module and included under the 'lib' folder, it is called `aps_request_ott` and looks something like this:

```
module Ott
...
def module_test
  "Module Test"
end
```

Included the paths in the `config/application.rb` like:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Finally I have a model called `rmodel` that looks like this:

```
class Rmodel < ApplicationRecord
    include Ott
    def model_module_test
        "Module test"
    end

end
```

Despite all this, whenever I try to call `Rmodel.model_module_test` I get the error: `NameError (uninitialized constant Rmodel::Ott):`

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: A simpler way to write it is `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')` as there is no need to create an array to add a single element.  Make sure you restart spring as well with `spring stop`. You can also solve this by placing the module in `/app/models/concerns` which  is autoloaded by default.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just change `config` to `Rails`? Something like that

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/lib)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

`require "#{Rails.root}/lib/aps_request_ott"`

on top of your `Rmodel` file if you want the module required only there.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ## config/application.rb

    #autoloads lib folder during development
    config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')

    #autoloads lib folder during development
    config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```